# Not able to use bcp commanline to inport data from | delimited file into temp table

Tags: sql-server, file, bcp

I am using bcp command line to load data from pipe delimited file into temp table like below:

```
Create table tempdb..##test
(
  test1 int,
  test2 int,
  test3 int
)
```

`Select @CMD='BCP "tempdb..##test" IN "'+@sourcefoler +@filename +'" -S '+@servername+' -t "|" -c -q -t -F 2'`

```
EXECUTE master..XPCMDSHELL @cmd
```

In file first row is header that's why I put 2 their "-c -q -t -F 2".
In case of temp table i am not able to load file but in case of normal table it will load into it. The reason I want to load it in temp table is I want to add new column in temp the table and then I want to queryout it in new file and the load that file into load them in final table with updated column.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Temp tables live only while session is active and cmd drops session just after import is finished - temp table cannot survive. You need to extend your batch with other steps to work with temp table (add column, update) and then make export in the same batch.

Comment: I didn't write that code but I use alter table code to add column and update code to update temp table and then I want to queryout that temp table into a new file with first row as header with | delimiter

Comment: Done need to change the date format which I am using as datetime to datetime 112 format so that no space should be present their